# Apply Style To All Columns Except the first

Tags: c#, radgrid, radgridview

I am attempting to use C# to apply a style to all columns in a grid except the first.  This is the syntax that I have, but it hits my `if()` statement and immediately leaves.

What would be the proper way to write this syntax?

```
foreach(GridColumn col in r.Columns)
{            
    if (col != r.MasterTableView.Columns[0])
    {
        col.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
    }
}
```

Comment: The foreach iterates a collection and then the `if` and its content goes to another collection, can this be a source of problems?

Comment: @Alejandro - how would I specify the if to iterate the collection?

Comment: Can't you use the Skip function in the foreach loop?

Comment: I personally don't think it exits the loop, but the problem is rather the fact, that you're always using index 1 inside your `if` and actually set the style to the same column, so only this is the result of your iteration. Or am I misunderstanding the concept of the radgridview?

Comment: @MarkKram - I have never used the skip function.  All I am after is setting the HorizontalAlign.Center element to all columns in the grid except the first

Comment: Indeed, `r.MasterTableView.Columns[1].ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;` should be `col.ItemStyle.[...]`

Comment: You are trying to match 2 object refs "col" and r.MasterTableView.Columns[0]. I presume these are not the same in terms of objects in memory. If you are trying to find the same named or indexed column then you need to check the column index/ordinal or name.. something like col.Index = r.MasterTableView.Columns[0].Index

Comment: @Wheels73 or just `col != r.Columns[0]` as this would be the same object

Comment: @Wheels73 - there is no index that I can use, but I tried setting it to col.OrderIndex != r.MasterTableView.Columns[0].OrderIndex and all text is still left aligned

Comment: I see.. so you just need to ignore the 1st column in r.columns. Yep, skip should do that in the foreach. Thought your issue was it not entering the if...

Comment: Here you go: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the first column in r.Columns and the first column in r.MasterTableView.Columns are never the same thing, so your if test always fails.

Assuming that r.Columns can be indexed, the simplest approach would be to change the foreach for a for and then check the index, as follows:

```
for( int columnIndex = 1 ; columnIndex < r.Columns.Count ; ++ columnIndex )
{            
    r.Columns[columnIndex].ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
}
```

As the set of columns is likely correctly 0-based, starting the "columnIndex" iterator variable from 1 means that the 0th column is skipped, and the style changes are applied to all the others.

As mentioned in the comments, you could also use the Linq Skip() function to start the foreach iteration from the second item, as:

```
foreach(GridColumn col in r.Columns.Skip(1))
{            
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hehe, I wanted to post an answer with `for(int colIndex=1...` but you changed your mind and edited your answer, so take my +1

Comment: Yeah, I initially put `for(int colIndex = 0` and an if test to skip the 0th one, then I re-read my code and facepalmed.  Thanks

Comment: This is not working for my RadGrid?  I even wrapped your for loop inside my foreach loop and nothing

Comment: In that case, you may need to apply the styles to the columns of the View rather than the grid itself.  Not being familiar with this particular grid, I would guess:

`for( int columnIndex = 1 ; columnIndex < r.MasterTableView.Columns.Count ; ++ columnIndex )
{
    r.MasterTableView.Columns[columnIndex].ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
}`

Wrapping one loop inside the other won't help unless you actually use the outer loop variable in the inner code, otherwise it'll just run the same code multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < r.Columns.Count; i++)
{        
    r.MasterTableView.Columns[i].ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `r.Columns` in your `for` conditions, and iterating through `r.MasterTableView.Columns` ? What if they do not have the same number of columns ?